# Rails, postgres, index on presence of column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, database-migration

I'm building a rails application where some documents in a collection will have geo information. I want to index these documents in the database so I can quickly grab only the ones that have non null values. I don't need the geo values, so some of them are null. The index should only hold records with non-null coordinates. The columns for the geo information are `latitude` and `longitude`. The index that I have built is:

`add_index :thing, [:latitude, :longitude]`

or, as lat and lng will always exist together it could be just:

`add_index :thing, :latitude`

But I'm not sure this is the optimum strategy for indexing on non-null-ness of a column.

What's the best strategy for indexing on non-null-ness of a column?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could find in the ActiveRecord documentation is to use a 'unique: true' constraint on the index. It will not permit duplicate coordinates, which will not allow for more than one [latitude: null, longitude: null] record. I'm assuming you do NOT require geo information, but are checking for both latitude and longitude when it is supplied.

```
add_index :documents, [:latitude, :longitude], unique: true
```